# SHarp shade edges, Blender

Tags: texturing

I'm making an earth in blender and the edge of the night is wavy and sharp.[image: Sharp edge]

and here is the picture of the shader editor.
[image: Shader Editer]

Comment: The shader setup looks unnecessarily complicated. But on top of that, “smooth/sharp shading” is a very specific thing and has nothing to do with the problem at hand. I recommend changing your question title to “making a twilight zone on earth model”

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer - I first marked the question as a duplicate (which it is), however I feel the feature highlighted in the answer is new enough (and neat enough) that it's worth sharing anew.

For quite some time, blender has had a problem with shadow "terminator" artifacts on low poly objects despite smooth shading. Up until recently, the solutions for mitigating this problem have been rather limited (usually involving baking a Normal Map from a more heavily subdivided version of the same mesh).

Recently (since 2.90) blender has added a **Shadow Terminator Offset** to the Cycles engine that seems to do a rather good job of overcoming this problem. The option can be found in the *Object Properties* tab:

[image: TerminatorFix]

For reference, this is the same object with the Terminator Offset set to 0 (off):

[image: TerminatorBad]